# UML use case diagram check user rights

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm currently writing an use case diagram for a module project for work. Basically, the project has one actor (the user, which is an employee). An example of one use case without anything special would be `Add slide to slideshow`. However, the slideshow has an website ID. So in order to be able to add a slide to the slideshow, the user has to have rights to that website.

I don't quite remember how I should add that to my diagram. I thought of this first:

[image: what I thought of]

But I'm not sure if this is done correctly. If not, how would I add the check that in order to `Add item`, your rights have to be checked first?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not correct. Authorization is no use case since it adds no value to what the actor is doing. It's a simple constraint and can be attached to either the actor (`{must logged on for Add Item}`) the UC (`{User must be logged on}`) or the association (`{login required}`).

Comment: The thing though is, if the use case diagram is completely made, there can be use cases where the rights aren't checked. Basically the system is one module. In order to get into the module, the user has to be logged in already. The user can add an item if he has rights to add an item, but when the user wants to translate an item, different kind of rights has to be checked ONLY for that use case (thus attaching it to the actor is a no-go from what I think). How would I attach it to the use case then?

Comment: Well, as I said: if you have restricted UCs attach a constraint `{login required}`.